# ActiveX does not automatically register when accessed via IE6

Tags: activex, regsvr32

I made an ActiveX control, placed it in an Object tag on an html file, placed that file on an https apache server. When i access the web page using my development machine, it works fine. I unregistered the activeX from my development machine, deleted all instances of the .ocx file , but it still runs successfully on my development machine. But when i try to access it from a different machine, it does not run and a small red x is displayed i found out that the .ocx file was successfully downloaded but did not show up in the objects list in internet explorer objects.

Can someone please help me, this is my first ActiveX control!

I am using Microsoft Internet Explorer 6 in Windows XP Service Pack 2

Best Regards,
HJ

Comment: I would suggest to ditch IE 6.....too old and buggy just like IE 4 ....should support the more modern browsers....

Comment: Thanks tommieb75 for your suggestion, but unfortunately, i am stuck with this version, its kind of a requirement. Is this a known issue?

Comment: I tried to register the activeX control manually (using RegSvr32) on this other machine, but it failed to register, and showed a message
"LoadLibrary("myActivex.ocx") failed - This application has failed to start because the application configuration is incorrect. Reinstalling the application may fix the problem."
What could have went wrong??
Any Idea??

Thanks,
HJ

Comment: I don't think this is a legit question, as no one is running Windows XP SP2 as SP3 is compulsory for any Internet connected system. It's just another one of those IE haters trying to act like an 8 year old browser is used in the real world.

Answer (score 0):

Check in "%windir%\Downloaded Program Files" and subdirectories for your control.  You should be able to delete everything there that is related to your control to get it back to the default state.

Comment: OK now I have moved to IE7, but here I am facing a different problem. The ActiveX control seems to have registered successfully but it is not appearing on the web page. I have removed all security settings in IE7. Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance
HJ

Comment: Set a breakpoint in your IObjectWithSite implementation and see if it gets called.